# Cannot convert an integer from a class to a .ToString string

Tags: c#, tostring

I have tried .ToString for a public integer in my class called pcc.

```
        private void pcb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sct = sc;
            player.pcc = player.pcc + 1 * player.multiplier;
            string sctstr = player.pcc.ToString;
        }
```

it gives me an error highlighting 'ToString' and the error is 'Cannot convert method group'ToString' to non-delgate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?'

Comment: There's the answer, use ToString();

Answer (score 0):

`ToString` is a method.  You want to use parenthesis to invoke it - `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

ToString is a method, so you need to put the parenthesis: TB0.Value.ToString().